# Security Patch SUPEE-10752 Issue with UPS Free Method (1.9.3.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-10752

We encountered a problem after SUPEE-10752. When trying to set "Free Method" for "UPS Type" "United Parcel Service XML". 
Magento throws an error when any method is selected in "Free Method" drop-down. Error: "Field "Ups Free Method" has wrong value."

I was able fix the error and able to succesfully save the "Free Method" but the configuration page will still show the value as "None" even though the value is set and saved properly to database.
Any advise how to make the field "Free Method" to show the selected method correctly?

```
<?php

class Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups_Source_Freemethod extends Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups_Source_Method
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
//        $arr = parent::toOptionArray();
        $ups = Mage::getSingleton('usa/shipping_carrier_ups');
        $arr = array();
        $isByCode = $ups->getConfigData('type') == 'UPS_XML';

        $methodlist = $ups->getCode('method');
        if ($isByCode) {
          $origin = $ups->getConfigData('origin_shipment');
          $methodlist = $ups->getcode('originShipment',$origin);
        }

        foreach ($methodlist as $k=>$v) {
            $arr[] = array('value'=>$k, 'label'=>Mage::helper('usa')->__($v));
        }

        array_unshift($arr, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('shipping')->__('None')));
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the code above. That works great if you only need the UPS_XML shipping type, but fails when you switch back to standard UPS. It did give me a great running start when I had to dive into the problem.

I tried multiple ways to get it to work for both methods and any shipping origin, but I started spiraling into some pretty poor code. In the end, I removed this check entirely because of the validation that is done on the form (PHTML) to create and validate the free shipping select list.

To remove the "Free Method" validation, create a local override of the Freemethod backend model by copying the original file -

*app/code/**core**/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/Freemethod.php*

to

*app/code/**local**/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups/Backend/Freemethod.php*

and add the following code

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    return $this;
}
```

My fix for the display of the field is to change the ups.phtml added by SUPEE-10752 (*app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/shipping/ups.phtml*) to filter the free method dropdown based on the shipping type (UPS or UPS_XML) -

change from

```
if ($storedFreeShipment != '' && !in_array($storedFreeShipment, array_keys($defShipArr))) {
    $storedFreeShipment = '';
}
```

to

```
if ($storedUpsType=='UPS') { //DEFAULT Type
    if ($storedFreeShipment != '' && !in_array($storedFreeShipment, array_keys($defShipArr))) {
        $storedFreeShipment = '';
    }    
} else {    //XML TYPE
    if ($storedFreeShipment != '' && !in_array($storedFreeShipment, array_keys($orShipArr[$storedOriginShipment]))) {
        $storedFreeShipment = '';
    }
}
```

Hopefully Magento will fix this someday and we can remove this.  Given some more time, I'll try to wrap this up into a small module that rather than change a core admin template.